# Built-in PDF viewer produces blurry PDF

Tags: pdftex, texstudio, texworks

I have used the built-in PDF viewer in both TexWorks and TexStudio to try to view my PDF. In both cases the PDF appears very blurry, with the letters looking very grainy. I have opened the PDF in Adobe Reader and it looks completely normal. This issue has just started and I haven't had any problems before opening TexWorks today. Is there any way to make the output PDF less blury? I am using MikTeX on Windows 10.

EDIT: Attached screenshot of code and output.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UeOv4.jpg

Comment: Can you please show us a short compilable tex code resulting in your blurry pdf? Can you add an screenshot too? For me that could also be an pdf viewer issue. Which pdf viewer do TeXWorks and TeXStudio use? Can you configurate is? If yes, please show the configurations ... BTW: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: @Mensch I've attached a link to a screenshot in my post. I'm not sure which pdf viewer TeXWorks and TeXStudio use, just that it is the built in-viewer. I opened the pdf shown in the screenshot in Adbobe and it looks fine.

Comment: Just for fun, try adding `\usepackage{lmodern}` . I tend to use TeXLive instead of MikTeX. TL has cm-super as the default font. It is a scalable (vector) font. The default font in MikTeX seems to be a bit map version of CM that renders poorly in certain viewers. Not sure how to make cm-super the default in MikTeX. It might be enough to just install `cm-super`.

Comment: @daleif I tried adding \usepackage{lmodern}, still looks the same unfortunately. Also installed cm-super, and still not working, but it is possible I didn't install/use it correctly. I'm more confused by the fact that this is happening now, because neither of those two packages were installed and it has been working fine for months.

Comment: What did you change/do before that happens? An windows update? version? An MikTex update? which version do you have now? Can you please show us a screenshot of your pdf viewer configuration for texworks and texstudio?